# Cómo usar autocompletado en NetBeans 12.4 para archivos JSP?

Tags: java, web, netbeans, jsp

Buenos dias estoy haciendo una pagina utilizando JSP pero ocurre que cuando hago una clase en java el autocompletado funciona bien, en el html igual todo funciona bien pero cuando creo un archivo.jsp e incluyo el codigo Java ya no me autocompleta y tampoco me remarca las variables que he declarado previamente, esperaria si alguien sabe como corregirlo, se lo agradecería

Comment: Sin mayúsculas sostenidas, por favor. Ahora bien: te pasa al escribir bloques que invocan cosas en un bean o escribiendo cualquier instrucción Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es totalmente normal que no te autocomplete ya que aunque escribas código en java no se procesa hasta que no viaja al servidor. Para que me entiendas mejor, al escribir código en un jsp es como escribirlo en una hoja de papel, solo se va a procesar cuando se la pases al servidor. No hay forma que se te autocomplete en el fichero jsp.
Te recomendaría que en vez de escribir código java en el jsp, crees un servlet en el que hagas toda la lógica de dicho jsp ya que será más cómodo (ya que podrás autocompletar) además de tener un programa muchísimo más limpio al separar la capa lógica de la capa de presentación.